# session_set_cookie_params array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string

When I try to set some cookie parameters in PHP using the `session_set_cookie_params` function, I get an error stating that I'm trying to convert an array to a string.

This is my code:

```
$cookie_params             = session_get_cookie_params();
$cookie_params['secure']   = true;
$cookie_params['samesite'] = "None";

session_set_cookie_params($cookie_params);
```

Any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 7.3 of PHP the `session_set_cookie_params` function accepts an array of options, including the `samesite` attribute. I was mixing some versions of PHP. Apparently my development environment changed the version of PHP it used to 7.0.33

If you're encountering this error, make sure both are at least 7.3, that will fix your error.

[Documentation on the function](https://www.php.net/session_set_cookie_params)

**Note:**

Yes, I answered my own question, but searching online in the way I am used to didn't quickly return any results that resolved my problem, which is why I choose to ask and answer my question (something StackOverflow allows you to do).

Comment: Have you just asked and answered your own question in 10s?

Comment: @RamRaider Since the website didn't turn up any results on my first attempt to solve the problem, I looked elsewhere and found the problem after about 15 minutes. To save anyone the same time, I posted and answered my question indeed, which is something the website offers (and I believe encourages) you to do.

Comment: Just seems peculiar that both question and answer were posted at the same time

Comment: @RamRaider When posting a question it has a checkbox "answer your own question Q&A style". When ticking that box it let's you add an answer immediately. I'll change it a bit more so it reads better.